# Add a view to a fragment from mainActivity

Tags: android, fragment, android-view

I Want to dynamically add a view to the fragments from this mainActivity.
since, Fragment class does not have `addView()` API, what are the other options available for me.
I tried `fragment.getView()` at line 1, but it gives nullpointer Exception. I am not well aware of the fragment api and dont have time to invest in going through it. Can anyone please provide a workaround for the problem.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tabA = bar.newTab().setText("A Tab");
    ActionBar.Tab tabB = bar.newTab().setText("B Tab");
    ActionBar.Tab tabC = bar.newTab().setText("C Tab");

    Fragment fragmentA = new AFragmentTab();
    Fragment fragmentB = new BFragmentTab();
    Fragment fragmentC = new CFragmentTab();

    tabA.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentA));
    tabB.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentB));
    tabC.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragmentC));

    bar.addTab(tabA);
    bar.addTab(tabB);
    bar.addTab(tabC);

        //Line 1
        //How to add a view from here to any of these fragment
        //Or how can i modify the content of that fragment

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

protected class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, null);
        // Or should the modification/addition of views be done here.           
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // some people needed this line as well to make it work: 
        ft.remove(fragment);
    }
}
}
```

**BFagmentTab.java**

```
public class BFragmentTab extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `fragment.getView()` in the `onResume()` or `onStart()` methods of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please Look into this : [One](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation-tabs.html) & [Two](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation.html)

Comment: My code is almost similar to yours, except that it doesnt use actionBarSherlock. And both achieve the same output, viz - tab view for the fragments. But i dont see any resemblance to what i asked for. I want to reflect the changes/ or modify - say - fragment 1 from fragment 2

Comment: Change your code. Actionbar to Fragment becoz i have also face this issue.

Comment: can you provide a working example for topic. say, a tabbed view with any dynamic content being added to the fragment from another activity

Comment: I have already provide you two links which have code you can also check this : https://github.com/dhaval0122/ActionBar-Navigation-Tabs here is code of tabs in FragmentActivity....